# how to show Relative layout in bottom?

Tags: android, layout

I created one linear layout and I have added two relative layout. I wish to show one layout in top another layout in bottom. My problem is both layout display in top. how to change 1layout top another one is bottom please help me.

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/blue"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55px"
        android:background="@drawable/testheader"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="settings"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReturn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="image" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55px"
        android:background="@drawable/testheader"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReturn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Return" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change your LinearLayout to RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/blue"

   >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55px"
        android:background="@drawable/testheader"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="settings"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" 
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReturn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="image" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


     <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55px"
        android:background="@drawable/testheader"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReturn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Return" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayout` and then create two inner relative layouts and one set with `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and second with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and then it will works how you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try Parentalayout with Relative layout.See the XML below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/blue"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55px"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:background="@drawable/testheader"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="settings"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReturn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="image" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55px"
        android:background="@drawable/testheader"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReturn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Return" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your linearLayout orientation to `vertical`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/blue"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

the parent layout should be a RelativeLayout , so you can positionne others layout on the top and on the bottom like this  :

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55px"
        android:background="@drawable/testheader"
        android:alignParentTop ="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="settings"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReturn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="image" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55px"
        android:background="@drawable/testheader"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnReturn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Return" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#F0F" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#F0F" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

In linear layout, change the orientation to vertical.